# Can't see C or D drives in Nautilus

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, nautilus

I am new to Ubuntu. Last week I installed *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS* alongside *Windows 10* on an Acer desktop. When first installed, if I opened files, I could see my windows partition Acer 'C' and data partition 'D'.

Today I wanted to move some music on 'D', but now neither are available. It is more 'D' that I want to access when you using Ubuntu.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If windows has 'fast boot' enabled; it's drives are left in a incomplete/unsafe state (ie. some file info remains in hibernated-memory and not written to the disk file-system), so Ubuntu won't mount such a drive as it could be working on wrong information (changed by data that hasn't been written to the disk by windows).  If this is your issue, you must disable 'fast boot' on windows before Ubuntu can 'mount' the drives safely.

Comment: @guiverc Although true I thought Nautilus gives you an error message telling you that Windows hasn't shutdown and is hibernating or something like that?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I was guessing, as the OP hasn't given us any specific error messages that I see. Kenny if you want a more specific answer to your problem, we need specific details (if possible) to avoid 'these possible-causes/guesses'.  Yes 'gui' tools hide many such things, so it may require looking, eg. using other tools like `gnome-disks` to get the clues (where on terminal they are just blurted out..)

Comment: @guiverc It's the phrase "they don't appear" which brings possibilities they aren't in `/etc/fstab` anymore or the `disks` program has been reconfigured to not show them in Nautilus anymore. But as you say exact error message is required or confirmation the drives simply don't appear on the left side-panel as the OP hints.

Comment: Fast start up is disabled  when I open Files there are no Window folders shown on gparted both partitions are there under NTFS format

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix there is no error message they simply no longer show anywhere on Ubuntu except in gparted

Answer (score 1):

Disabling [Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)/[Hybrid Sleep](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/difference-between-sleep-hybrid-sleep-and-hibernation-in-windows-7) will resolve your no-access problem.  It will require booting into Windows 10, where you perform

```
{Win-R} powercfg.cpl {Enter}
```

Look for selected power plan (bullet in circle) and click its 'Change plan settings' link.
Click on **Change advanced power settings**
Expand **Sleep**, then expand **Allow hybrid sleep** 
Set it to **Off**
On a laptop, likely you will see two options, **On battery** and **Plugged In** 
Set both of those to **Off**
Click **OK** then **Save Changes**
Shut down Windows completely, power up, choose Ubuntu, and those drives should appear in Nautilus once more.